# throwing a StaleElementReferenceException during dictionary iteration in a for loop

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, automated-tests, staleelementreferenceexception

The following code is provided below:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class BaseClass {
    protected static ChromeDriver chromeDriver;

    @BeforeEach
    public void before() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getenv("CHROME_DRIVER"));
        chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver();
        chromeDriver.manage().window().maximize();
        chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        chromeDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @AfterEach
    public void after() {
        chromeDriver.quit();
    }

}
```

```
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.*;

public class NotebookListPage {
    private static NotebookListPage instance;
    private ChromeDriver chromeDriver;
    private WebDriverWait wait;
    private Actions actions;
    public Dictionary<String, List<PageItem>> onePageCatalog = new Hashtable<>();
    private int currentPage = 0;

    private NotebookListPage(ChromeDriver chromeDriver) {
        this.chromeDriver = chromeDriver;
        this.wait = new WebDriverWait(chromeDriver, 22);
        wait.pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(4));
        wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
        this.actions = new Actions(chromeDriver);
    }
    
    public static synchronized NotebookListPage getInstance(ChromeDriver chromeDriver) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new NotebookListPage(chromeDriver);
        }
        return instance;
    }
    private WebElement getLowPriceField() {
        return chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-auto='filter-range-glprice']/descendant::span[@data-auto='filter-range-min']/descendant::input[@type='text']"));
    }

    private WebElement getHighPriceField() {
        return chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-auto='filter-range-glprice']/descendant::span[@data-auto='filter-range-max']/descendant::input[@type='text']"));
    }

    private WebElement getLenovoButton() {
        return chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@data-auto='filter-list-item-152981']/descendant::span[@class='_1Mp5C']"));
    }

    private WebElement getHPButton(){
        return chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@data-auto='filter-list-item-152722']/descendant::span[@class='_1Mp5C']"));
    }

    private WebElement getRecommendation() {
        return chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-grabber = 'SearchRecommendations']"));
    }

    private List<WebElement> getItems() {
        return chromeDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@data-apiary-widget-name = '@light/Organic']"));
    }

    private List<WebElement> getForward() {
        return chromeDriver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[@class='_3e9Bd']"));
    }


    private WebElement getCurrentPage() {
        return chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div/div[@class='Xe4rX _18sEx _3-NJO']"));
    }
    
    public void initFilters(String lowPrice, String highPrice) throws InterruptedException {

        getLowPriceField().click();
        getLowPriceField().sendKeys(lowPrice);

        getHighPriceField().click();
        getHighPriceField().sendKeys(highPrice);

        getLenovoButton().click();
        getHPButton().click();
    }

    public void Parsing() {
        currentPage = currentPage + 1;
        onePageCatalog.put(Integer.toString(currentPage), new ArrayList<>());
        actions.moveToElement(getRecommendation()).perform();
        for (int i = 0; i < getItems().size(); ++i) {
            String name = getItems().get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//h3[@data-auto='snippet-title']")).getText();
            String stringPrice = getItems().get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='_3MgRl']")).getText().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
            int price = Integer.parseInt(stringPrice);
            onePageCatalog.get(Integer.toString(currentPage)).add(new PageItem(name, price));
        }
        if (!getForward().isEmpty()) {
            getForward().get(0).click();
            wait.until(d -> Integer.parseInt(getCurrentPage().getText()) != currentPage);
            Parsing();
        }

    }
}

public class PageItem {
    String name;
    int price;

    public PageItem(String name, int price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}

The meaning of the last part of the code is that when iterating the dictionary in the for loop, a web element is searched for on a web page and immediately converted to a string. However, in line "107", namely: 
" String string Price = getItems().get(i).findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='_3MgRl']")).getText().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");" 
StaleElementReferenceException is thrown. I can't understand how it may be possible. It is me second version of code, and in the end, I still come to the conclusion that I need to iterate the dictionary/map and parse it from the WebElement format to the String format.
```

If you can explain what the problem is and help me solve this problem, I will be very grateful!

in early versions of the program, before the for loop and in the loop itself, I refreshed the locator, but it didn't help either.

as far as I understand, the locator becomes irrelevant immediately after the search until it is converted to text. But I can't figure out how to fix it.

Comment: this can happen if you get the webelement reference array while the DOM is still updating.  Easy fix is to just add a sleep before using findElements...

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I just don't fully understand how the loading of a DOM and the staleness of a web element are related. Could you explain it?

Comment: what you receive is an array of references to webelements in the DOM at the time that you call that findElements method.  While iterating if the DOM changes, all those references will become stale. They are no longer valid as the DOM has updated and those references are tied, via UIDs I think, to the DOM before the update.  This means you need to re-get the references.   Also see here: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/#stale-element-reference-exception

Comment: @browsermator, I got you. Thanks to your advice, I fixed the code by creating methods that would search for an element without accessing the list elements.
` private WebElement getName(int i) {
        return chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("(//h3[@data-auto='snippet-title'])[" + i + "]"));
    }`
private WebElement getPrice(int i) {
        return chromeDriver.findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='_3MgRl'])[" + i + "]"));
    }
But I still get StaleElementRef-ceException in one of the two lines:
`String name = getName(i + 1).getText();
 String strprice = getPrice(i + 1).getText();`

Comment: @browsermator could you please tell what's the problem in my case?

Comment: I don't see those methods, but it's probably the same thing... at the time you get those elements, the DOM is still updating.  (the elements are there, but the DOM is still being updated... between the time you get the element reference and the time you use the .getText() method, an update has occured)